# Accepting cookies popups using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to put together a small scraper for public trademark data. I have a database available that i'm using selenium and python to access.
I can do just about anything I need to be able to, but for some reason i can't actually click the "accept cookies" button on the website. The following code i use highlights the button, but it does not get rid of the popup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://data.inpi.fr/recherche_avancee/marques')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tarteaucitronPersonalize2"))
        ).click()
```

I have looked up similar threads on this forum, and I have tried multiple things :

```
- adding a waiting period, that ended up highlighting the button, so at least i know it does something
- using javascript code to do the actual click, did not work any better
- i tried calling the button via its ID, its XPATH, its CSS selector, anything i could find really
```

I even downloaded Selenium IDE to record my clicks to see exactly how I could replicate it, but it still only recorded a click.

I tried my best, does anyone know where my mistake lie ? I am open to using other languages, or another platform

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like I managed to solve it just minutes after posting my question !
For some reason you need to resize the window. I just added the following line of code after opening the URL and it worked first time.
`driver.maximize_window()`

I added this answer in case anyone stumbles upon this post and wants to avoid pulling their hair out over this !